# Web Crawling and Link Evaluation

Tags: web-crawler

I know that cURL will download a complete file.

What I really want is to take all links on a page and evaluate against my specific criteria, location of the link, etc and decide if I should grab that page and parse it for information.

More specifically, I want to find links that pertain to entertainment events and parse the data and store it in my MySQL database to populate a website for events in my area.

Would anyone have thoughts on how to accomplish?

-Jason

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you base your effort on an existing web crawler/indexer solution, rather than implement it yourself in code or with tools such as CURL.

See [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/), for instance.

Comment: how does one deploy this at GoDaddy on a shared server?

Comment: And second, on a mac mini with a static IP?

Answer (score 1):

Those solutions in the other answers sounds interesting, but I just did something similar and simple with [C#/Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) and [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is an enumeration of links on a page, you can use the .NET WebBrowser and the DOM to do that.  Digging up my code for this... I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a programming language. [Apache Droids](http://incubator.apache.org/droids/) may be the thing for you, if you are willing to customize it using Java. It is planned as a minimal crawler that you can customize for your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you didn't mention a language.  If your using Ruby, the cobweb gem could be used for this.  You would manually tell it not to find any links (it would automatically crawl  all links by default) and do this yourself on each page as you said you needed to evaluate them, they could then manually be put into the queue if you want them to be crawled.

It appears as though Ruby on Rails is supported by godaddy shared hosting if thats what your on.

( just saw this was 3 years ago, might help someone else though! )